# Safe `maximum` in Haskell Standard Library?

Tags: haskell

Is there a safe equivalent of `maximum` in Haskell's Standard Library?

```
*Main Control.Monad.State Data.List> maximum []
*** Exception: Prelude.maximum: empty list
```

I tried to find one, `(Ord a, Foldable t) => t a -> Maybe a` with [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28Ord+a%2C+Foldable+t%29+%3D%3E+t+a+-%3E+Maybe+a), but found none.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the sake of completeness: loosening your "Standard Library" requirement to "some very commonly used library", the *safe* package provides the [`Safe.Foldable` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-0.3.14/docs/Safe-Foldable.html), which includes a `maximumMay` function:

```
maximumMay :: (Foldable t, Ord a) => t a -> Maybe a
```

Answer (score 6):

You can code one up yourself for any `Foldable`, by applying `foldMap` to a suitable choice of `Monoid`.

[The `Option` monoid](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Option) takes an existing `Semigroup` and lifts it into a `Monoid` by adjoining an empty element (`Option Nothing`), which'll be returned by `foldMap` if the input `Foldable` is empty. [The `Max` newtype](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Max) lifts any instance of `Ord` into a `Semigroup` by making `<>` pick the larger of its arguments.

So by `foldMap`ping the input `Foldable` through the composition of `Option` and `Max`, we get your desired behaviour.

```
safeMaximum :: (Foldable t, Ord a) => t a -> Maybe a
safeMaximum = fmap getMax . getOption . foldMap (Option . Just . Max)

ghci> safeMaximum "wowzers"
Just 'z'
ghci> safeMaximum ""
Nothing
```

Comment: The `Otpion` is no longer needed, the same result will be achieved by writing:
`safeMaximum = fmap getMax . foldMap (Just . Max)`

Answer (score 3):

You could create your own:

```
maximumMaybe :: (Ord a, Foldable f) => f a -> Maybe a
maximumMaybe xs
  | null xs   = Nothing
  | otherwise = Just $ maximum xs
```

**Previous Answer** (not foldable):

```
maximumMaybe :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
maximumMaybe xs = listToMaybe xs *> Just (maximum xs)
```

Or if you like *point-free* style:

```
maximumMaybe :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
maximumMaybe = (<*) . Just . maximum <*> listToMaybe
```

Another, simpler, solution is:

```
maximumMaybe :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
maximumMaybe [] = Nothing
maximumMaybe xs = Just $ maximum xs
```

Comment: Another point-free way, using Data.List.NonEmpty (now in base): `fmap maximum . nonEmpty`.

Comment: Nice one! :D I need to use `NonEmpty` more.